How to access container's python packages from the host?
I would like to have local read access to the Python packages that my docker container process installs.
I thought the easiest way to do this would be to "symlink" a local file to a directory on the container's directory, which I thought I could do with volumes/mounts.
I have tried many different methods:
services:
  django:
    volumes:
      - /tmp/docker-django-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages

Problem: /tmp/docker-django-packages is not created if it doesn't exist, but there is no docker error, however no python packages can be resolved by the container's python process. If I manually make /tmp/docker-django-packages on the host, then I still get the same error.
services:
  django:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /tmp/docker-django-packages
        target: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
        bind:
          create_host_path: true

Problem: /tmp/docker-django-packages is not created. If I make it manually, it is not populated. The container behaviour is not affected at all.
services:
  django:
    volumes:
      - docker-django-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages

volumes:
  docker-django-packages:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/tmp/docker-django-packages"

Problem: host directory not created if it doesn't exist, not populated if it already exists, and the container functions as normal
services:
  django:
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: docker-django-packages
        target: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages


volumes:
  docker-django-packages:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/tmp/docker-django-packages"

Problem: host directory not created, nor populated, container yet again functions as if these lines weren't in the compose file at all
services:
  django:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: docker-django-packages
        target: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages


volumes:
  docker-django-packages:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/tmp/docker-django-packages"

Problem: nothing changes on the host machine (no new directory, no new contents if I make it manually), but the container python process can no longer find. Also seems to require making the service privileged for the first run. Also seems to do some kind of caching, if I remove the privileged permission for subsequent runs, the container starts but I just get python import errors.

So what am I actually meant to do so that I can mirror the container's Python packages on the host machine?

Docker bind mounts only go in the opposite direction, taking content from the host system and replacing directories in the container with them.  It looks like the directory you're trying to access is a Python library folder; putting Docker aside and using a plain Python virtual environment might work better for this use case.

@DavidMaze so you think I should manage the container's Python packages on the host?

No, I think if you want to directly look at the files pip install installs, then you don't want an isolation environment like Docker, and you should use standard non-container Python tools (pip, Hatch, Poetry, pyenv, ...).  You probably cannot reuse these libraries with other Pythons (especially if C extensions are involved) and you really shouldn't directly edit the installed library files.

@DavidMaze the only reason I want to look at the packages is so that my LSP can see them while I'm developing for a container

Use pip freeze > requirements.txt to generate a package list, then use pip install -r requirements.txt in your docker nodes as well as on your development station. That'll make the python packages match without crossing Docker's isolation boundary.

@Vegard I was hoping there would be a solution that doesn't require installing all packages twice. This also has the downside of requiring me to manually sync the two environments every time the dependencies change

I'd recommend taking Docker out of your development critical loop.  The native Python tooling is very well established and there's no particular reason to insert an unnecessary isolation system into it.  You'll also have trouble running debuggers and tests, and there are somewhat frequent SO reports of Docker bind mounts not promptly updating the container filesystem.
